# How to convert PostGis Table (Grid data) to Continuous field using Qgis?

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, layers

I'd like to transform my Gridded Layer (generated form a PostGIS table of points) to a continuous and colored layer. How could I do this with Qgis or any other program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two gdal functions in the QGIS Raster menu that you can use.

- If the points are already in a regular grid, then you can use gdal_rasterize. In the Menu: Raster->Conversion->Rasterize. Make sure to set the target resolution the same as the spacing of the points.
- You can also to choose to interpolate a raster from the points using gdal_grid. Raster->Analysis->Grid(Interpolation). This will work for any reasonable target resolution, and irregularly spaced points.

HTH